# Convert CartoCSS to Mapbox GL Style

Tags: mapbox

I was trying to get an map style from the old Mapbox Studio Classic (https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-classic-styles/) running in the new Mapbox Studio, i.e., converting it to Mapbox GL Style. I am wondering if there's a way to to convert at least the most part automatically?

Here's an example:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-winter-wonderland.tm2

Comment: I'm actually wondering how to do the opposite, from Mapbox GL Style to CartoCSS, since the Map library I use doesn't seem to support Mapbox GL Style. Did you get to anything with this matter?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea Nothing automatic unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I did not.